# Excel autofill inconsistent

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-auto-fill

I'm working in an excel spreadsheet that I add data to each day as new data comes in. Some columns are formulas calculating things based on the new data. Some of these columns have managed to automatically copy the formula for the past several days as the new data is entered into the new row. As I have increased the number of columns and thereby the number of calculation columns, I've noticed that the newly inserted columns won't do the same automatic filling as the previous columns, and I'm not sure why. The formulas are a simple copy down the column, but I would like each new row to automatically figure out the formula once the data is entered into the new row.

For example:
Column A is a number
Column B is a formula - =A2-A1
Column C is a rolling average - =AVERAGE(B1:B3)

My current sheet will fill in the formula for column B once I input data in column B, but will not do the same for column C

Comment: Are you saying that the formulas don't exist in those cells until you add the data?  Or are you dragging down the formulas after you enter the new data?

Comment: To atart the spreadsheet, i dragged down the formulas.  Ow, the formulas automatically copy themselves when i enter the data, and others do not (as the example above). Does that clarify?

Comment: I still don't understand enough to tell you why it would work sometimes and not others.  Recommend that you look at @DeNaeL 's answer below.  Any reason you can't use a table?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have tried converting the data to a table, with the same effect when I add a row. Is there some setting I’m missing, allowing the columns I added later to be auto-filled?

Comment: Are you appending the data to the bottom of the table or inserting it between existing rows?

Comment: I’m adding to the bottom of the table

Comment: OK, so are you dragging the right corner of the table down to add rows?  I get weird results even from inserting a row at the bottom.  I still get formulas, just not what I expected.

Comment: "once I input data in column B" <-- just to clarify.. is column B a 'data' column or it is actually filled with `=A2-A1` formula ? || "will not do the same for column C" <-- since formula in column C needs at least 3 numbers in column B & 4 numbers from column A to work. I see a problem of value dependencies here.. || A sample data and sample/screenshot of your intended output would help to clarify this Q .. ( :

Comment: Thanks for all of your help... as @ReyJuna suggested, dragging down the table from the bottom right fixes this mostly. I think what I’ve figured out is that it will auto fill all of the formulae as I expand the table except for one... that one is calculated based on a calculated value from another copied formula. So my guess is that excel won’t auto-fill it because it’s based on another formula. Not sure if that’s true or not, but it’s the best I can figure out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found Excel tables to be very valuable for managing this type of auto-fill.

1. Select all of your data, including your column headers.
2. On the "Insert" tab, select "Table."
3. Check the box which indicates that your data has headers.

Now, when you enter a formula in one cell in a column, Excel will automatically fill the other cells in the column with that formula.

When you add a row to the table, the formulas will be added.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I tried converting the data to a table, but I’m running into the same problem. Is there something I’m missing?

Comment: @Elliott I've noticed with tables, that if there is a single entry in the row/column that does not match the others, formulas won't auto-fill.